# Using HttpWebRequest and GET method for login

Tags: get, httpwebrequest

Im having problems using HttpWebRequest and POST method to send info to a third party server to validate a username, i keep getting error 405 not method allowed, so i was thinking if it is possible to make a login using the method GET, but i have no knowledge about this topic so i would like to ask for some help, a tutorial or reference or if someone has a small method.

well thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using GET instead of POST, you just add the parameters to the query string instead.

```
http://domain.com/login?username=<username>&password=<password>
```

Is the same as POSTing a form with two values, username and password.

Comment: Thanks, but then i just use, request.getresponse() ? and a stream to read the answer?

Comment: The response is no different when doing a POST or a GET. A response is a response.

Answer (score 1):

Use GET for login is a bad idea. GET essentially sends all the data in the URL which is not quite safe always. GET also is idempotent (bookmarkable). You would never want your login information to be bookmarkable (through URL)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i know it not safe, but the problem its that the server it seems doesnt support POST, so i want to try using GET for testing , because i dont know the full specification of the server.

Comment: send a HTTP OPTIONS request to see what are the HTTP methods supported (by that URL)